# Change background of multiple windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, background, tkinter

I am trying to make a settings menu in my program so you can change the background for all windows in the program. But I don't know how to make it so when you click the button, the background changes. Any help? Here's what I have so far if needed:

```
    #Settings
    class programSettings(tk.Frame):

        #Initialize
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            #Setups
            title = ttk.Label(self, text = "Settings", font = LARGE_FONT)

            colorButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Background Color", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(color))
            menuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Main Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

            #Placement
            title.pack()
            colorButton.pack()
            menuButton.pack()

    #Color
    class color(tk.Frame):

        #Initialize
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            #Setups
            blueButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Blue", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(programSettings))
            blueButton.configure(bg = "#4285F4")
            #Placement
            blueButton.pack()
```

It's not much and I have tried a few things, but they haven't worked.

Comment: You need a reference to all the "windows" you want to change the background in the current top-level window. Once you have it, you can simply call the `config` method and the property `background`

Comment: @Rinzler How can I reference all the windows? I'm learning Python so I don't know too much.

Comment: Learn first Python and then pass to tkinter, otherwise you will have much more problems..

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions: keep a reference to each window and use the `configure` method to change the background, or create a function that will recreate your whole UI after you change some global values.

Here's a rough outline of how you do the first method:

```
class ControllerClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.windows = []
        ...
    def show_frame(self, frame_class):
        ...
        the_frame = frame_class(root, self)
        self.windows.append(the_frame)
        ...
    def change_color(self):
        ...
        for frame in self.windows:
            frame.configure(background=the_color)
        ...
```

Of course, it should be a bit more complex than that. For example, your controller might have a "settings" dictionary rather than a single color. Also, you might consider having each window object be responsible for changing its own color, so you might do `frame.set_color(the_color)`. That way each window can not only set the background of itself, but any related children windows.